# Repeat Local notifications for selected days at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

In my app I am using UILocalNotifications. I want a functionality in which user can repeat alarms for specific days. Like(Monday,Wednesday,Sunday) at say 9pm. How can i do this.
Thanks in Advance

I am using the following code

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification setAlertBody:alertBody];
[notification setFireDate:[myDatePicker date]];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber+1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a `repeatInterval` property on the noitification , use that.

Comment: Yes.But how to get the days to fire

Answer (score 0):

Err... ...why don't just schedule three notifications for the three days, each with a week as `repreatInterval`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
NSDate *AlarmTime1 =[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:expiretime];
            UIApplication *app1 = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
            UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            if (notifyAlarm1) {
                notifyAlarm1.fireDate = AlarmTime1;
                notifyAlarm1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                 notifyAlarm.repeatInterval=0;
                 notifyAlarm.soundName= @"applering_zwnNYFkA.wav";
                notifyAlarm1.soundName=@"stop.wav";
                notifyAlarm1.alertBody =NSLocalizedString(@"EXPIRE_DESC", nil);
                [app1 scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm1];
```

Comment: I need to repeat for specific day, not all days.